# How to configure Angular 2 with Spring MVC

Tags: angular, maven, spring-mvc, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-config

I want to learn how to integrate Spring MVC with Angular 2.

I have some questions:

1)Any good links to learn Angular 2?

2)Does Angular 2 has more support(from solutions point of view)?

3)Any links for referring examples for Spring MVC with Angular 2?

Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: You can take a look @ this link for Angular 

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

taking into consideration Integrating it with Spring Just make a Rest Api in Spring or Spring boot and then use it in Angular Services